# Imageview to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, android-studio, imageview, firebase-storage

I have thoroughly confused myself on this.  I think it's way simpler than I have it, but I've tried so many things.

Activity Goals:

1.) Open the phone camera and take a picture of the front of an ID. (Works)

2.) Update an ImageView with that picture/ID. (Works)

3.) Upload the ImageView to Firebase storage.  (Doesn't work)

I think I've botched up the processing order.  I really don't want to submit to Firebase until the submit button is selected (openSubmitIdtoStorage), but I think it tries to do that immediately after updating the ImageView.  I've tried multiple variants and am stuck.  Seems like I'm complicating this way too much.  I think I just need another set of eyes to point me in the right direction.  Don't need a coding solution, just some thoughts on what I should be looking at.

Thanks!

```
package com.mm.mm;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.j2objc.annotations.Weak;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicMarkableReference;

public class RegisterID extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public String IDIssuer_Str = "Default";
    ActivityResultLauncher <Intent> activityResultLauncherfront;
    //ActivityResultLauncher <Intent> activityResultLauncherback;
    //ActivityResultLauncher <Intent> activityResultLauncherselfie;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_id);

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        Spinner IDIssuerSpinner = findViewById(R.id.ID_Issuer_Spin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ID_Issuer_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.ID_Issuer_List, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ID_Issuer_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        IDIssuerSpinner.setAdapter(ID_Issuer_adapter);
        IDIssuerSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Set variables for the front of the ID
        Button FrontIDImage_Btn = findViewById(R.id.IDFront_Btn);
        ImageView Front_Image_id = findViewById(R.id.IDFront_image);

        //Set variables for the back of the ID
        Button BackIDImage_Btn = findViewById(R.id.IDBack_Btn);
        ImageView Back_Image_id = findViewById(R.id.IDBack_image);

        //Set variables for a selfie button
        Button SelfieIDImage_Btn = findViewById(R.id.Selfie_Btn);
        ImageView Selfie_Image_id = findViewById(R.id.Selfie_image);

        //Set variables for a submit button
        Button SubmitFileToStorage = findViewById(R.id.Submit_IDs_Btn);

        //Actions when the Front ID Button is selected
        FrontIDImage_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent front_ID_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                activityResultLauncherfront.launch(front_ID_intent);
            }
        });

        //Launch Camera for Front of ID camera picture
        activityResultLauncherfront = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    Bundle frontExtras = result.getData().getExtras();
                    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) frontExtras.get("data");
                    Front_Image_id.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    WeakReference<Bitmap> FrontResult=new WeakReference<>(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                            bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), false).copy
                            (Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true));

                    Bitmap FrontBM=FrontResult.get();
                    saveFrontImage(FrontBM, RegisterID.this);
            }
        });


        SubmitFileToStorage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openSubmitIDtoStorage();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        switch(adapterView.getId()) {
            case (R.id.ID_Issuer_Spin):
                IDIssuer_Str = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    }

    private Uri saveFrontImage(Bitmap FrontImage, Context context) {

        File imagesFolder=new File(context.getCacheDir(), "images");
        Uri uri=null;

        try {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            File file=new File (imagesFolder, "capture_Front_ID.jpg");
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            FrontImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 200, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(context.getApplicationContext(), "com.mm.mm"+".provider", file);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return uri;
    }

    public void openSubmitIDtoStorage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will definitely help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).